# plugin to stop redirecting to cart from checkout

Tags: magento2, php, redirect, plugin, interceptor

In M2 if the user tries to go to the checkout without any items in their cart the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index::execute()` function redirects them to the cart.

```
if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError() || !$quote->validateMinimumAmount()) {
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
}
```

I would like to change this behaviour and enable them to move directly to the checkout. *(in the module I've created they can add a product to the cart from checkout)*.

I've tried doing this with the below [Plugin Interceptor](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) after method, but it gives a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error in my browser.

```
public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index $subject,
    $result
) {

    $result->setPath('checkout');
    return $result;
}
```

Any idea, how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

**You did the wrong on afterExecute**.

**I don't think you can achieve this  using via plugin.**

To achieve this you should override this Action class.
And remove this redirection:

```
if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError() || !$quote->validateMinimumAmount()) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
```

First create `di.xml` at `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/frontend` to **define class rewrite**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index"
                 type="{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Controller\Index\Index" />
 </config>
```

Then Define the **redirection class** `Index.php` at `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Controller/Index/`.

```
<?php

namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
{
    /**
     * Checkout page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper */
        $checkoutHelper = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data::class);
        if (!$checkoutHelper->canOnepageCheckout()) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('One-page checkout is turned off.'));
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }

        $quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
        // comment this condition 

        /*
        if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError() || !$quote->validateMinimumAmount()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        */

        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && !$checkoutHelper->isAllowedGuestCheckout($quote)) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Guest checkout is disabled.'));
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }

        $this->_customerSession->regenerateId();
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->setCartWasUpdated(false);
        $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Checkout'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```